# Is the minimal cover of {A->B,B->A} itself?

Tags: database-normalization, functional-dependencies

I ask this because I seem to lose information when I remove one the FDs and convert the relation to 3NF.

Comment: If you want this to be shown, you have to start with *definitions* of FD, cover & minimal cover and *procedures* that have been shown to produce covers & minimal covers from given schemas & sets of FDs that hold in them.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a relation with two attributes `R(A,B)` and the two dependencies `{A→B, B→A}`, then the dependencies are already a minimal cover, and you cannot remove one of them.

Note that in this case the relation is already in Boyce-Codd Normal Form and in Third Normal Form, and A and B are both candidate keys.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I had a relation with more FDs and attributes, but this was the essence of my question. Cheers